# Stuck with "Practical Django Projects"

Tags: django

Got another error with this tutorial. Should I give up and move on to another? …
Anyway.. here it goes:

```
Environment:

Request Method: GET
Request URL: http://127.0.0.1:8000/admin/
Django Version: 1.2.5
Python Version: 2.5.4
Installed Applications:
['django.contrib.auth',
 'django.contrib.contenttypes',
 'django.contrib.sessions',
 'django.contrib.sites',
 'django.contrib.messages',
 'django.contrib.admin',
 'django.contrib.flatpages',
 'cms.search',
 'coltrane',
 'tagging']
Installed Middleware:
('django.middleware.common.CommonMiddleware',
 'django.contrib.sessions.middleware.SessionMiddleware',
 'django.middleware.csrf.CsrfViewMiddleware',
 'django.contrib.auth.middleware.AuthenticationMiddleware',
 'django.contrib.messages.middleware.MessageMiddleware')


Traceback:
File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.5/lib/python2.5/site-packages/django/core/handlers/base.py" in get_response
  91.                         request.path_info)
File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.5/lib/python2.5/site-packages/django/core/urlresolvers.py" in resolve
  215.             for pattern in self.url_patterns:
File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.5/lib/python2.5/site-packages/django/core/urlresolvers.py" in _get_url_patterns
  244.         patterns = getattr(self.urlconf_module, "urlpatterns", self.urlconf_module)
File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.5/lib/python2.5/site-packages/django/core/urlresolvers.py" in _get_urlconf_module
  239.             self._urlconf_module = import_module(self.urlconf_name)
File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.5/lib/python2.5/site-packages/django/utils/importlib.py" in import_module
  35.     __import__(name)

Exception Type: SyntaxError at /admin/
Exception Value: invalid syntax (urls.py, line 6)
```

Here's the urls:

```
from django.conf.urls.defaults import *

from coltrane.models import Entry

entry_info_dict = {
    'queryset': Entry.objects.all(),
    'date_field': 'pub_date',
}

urlpatterns = patterns('django.views.generic.date_based',
    (r'^$', 'archive_index', entry_info_dict, 'coltrane_entry_archive_index'),

    (r'^(?P<year>\d{4})/$', 'archive_year', entry_info_dict, 'coltrane_entry_archive_year'),

    (r'^(?P<year>\d{4})/(?P<month>\w{3})/$', 'archive_month', entry_info_dict, 'coltrane_entry_archive_month'),

    (r'^(?P<year>\d{4})/(?P<month>\w{3})/(?P<day>\d{2})/$', 'archive_day', entry_info_dict, 'coltrane_entry_archive_day'),

    (r'^(?P<year>\d{4})/(?P<month>\w{3})/(?P<day>\d{2})/(?P<slug>[-\w]+)/$', 'object_detail', entry_info_dict, 'coltrane_entry_detail'),
)
```

I guess the error is on entry_info_dict. Any help? Thanks in advance.

Here's the models.py:

```
import datetime
from django.conf import settings
from django.db import models
from django.contrib.auth.models import User
from tagging.fields import TagField
from markdown import markdown
import tagging

class Category(models.Model):
    title = models.CharField(max_length=250, help_text='Maximum 250 characters.')
    slug = models.SlugField(help_text="Suggested value automatically generated from title. Must be unique.")
    description = models.TextField()

    class Meta:
        ordering = ['title']
        verbose_name_plural = "Categories"

    def __unicode__(self):
        return self.title

    @models.permalink
    def get_absolute_url(self):
        return ('coltrane_category_detail', (), { 'slug': self.slug })

class Entry(models.Model):
    LIVE_STATUS = 1
    DRAFT_STATUS = 2
    HIDDEN_STATUS = 3
    STATUS_CHOICES = (
        (LIVE_STATUS, 'Live'),
        (DRAFT_STATUS, 'Draft'),
        (HIDDEN_STATUS, 'Hidden'),
    )

    # Core fields
    title = models.CharField(max_length=250)
    excerpt = models.TextField(blank=True)
    body = models.TextField()
    pub_date = models.DateTimeField(default=datetime.datetime.now)

    # Metadata
    author = models.ForeignKey(User)
    enable_comments = models.BooleanField(default=True)
    featured = models.BooleanField(default=False)
    slug = models.SlugField(unique_for_date='pub_date')
    status = models.IntegerField(choices=STATUS_CHOICES, default=LIVE_STATUS)

    # Categorization
    categories = models.ManyToManyField(Category)
    tags = TagField()

    # Fields to store generated HTML
    excerpt_html = models.TextField(editable=False, blank=True)
    body_html = models.TextField(editable=False, blank=True)

    class Meta:
        verbose_name_plural = "Entries"
        ordering = ['-pub_date']

    def save(self, force_insert=False, force_update=False):
        self.body_html = markdown(self.body)
        if self.excerpt:
            self.excerpt_html = markdown(self.excerpt)
        super(Entry, self).save(force_insert, force_update)

    def __unicode__(self):
        return self.title

    @models.permalink
    def get_absolute_url(self):
        return ('coltrane_entry_detail', (), { 'year': self.pub_date_strftime("%Y"), 'month': self.pub_date_strftime("%b").lower(), 'day': self.pub_date.strftime("%d"), 'slug': self.slug })
```

Here's the main urls.py

```
from django.conf.urls.defaults import *
from django.contrib import admin
import settings
admin.autodiscover()

from coltrane.models. import Entry

urlpatterns = patterns('',
    # Example:
    # (r'^cms/', include('cms.foo.urls')),

    # Uncomment the admin/doc line below to enable admin documentation:
    # (r'^admin/doc/', include('django.contrib.admindocs.urls')),

    # Uncomment the next line to enable the admin:
    (r'^admin/', include(admin.site.urls)),
    (r'^search/$', 'cms.search.views.search'),
    (r'tiny_mce/(?P<path>.*)$', 'django.views.static.serve', { 'document_root': '/Users/danielcorreia/Sites/tinymce/jscripts/tiny_mce' }),
    (r'^weblog/', include('coltrane.urls')),
    (r'', include('django.contrib.flatpages.urls')),
)
```

Comment: Your model have a "live" manager?

Comment: Can you paste your models.py?

Comment: Not sure what you mean but I pasted the models.py

Comment: In your entry_info_dict dict, change Entry.live.all() for Entry.objects.all().

Comment: Same error still showing up. Don't know where I got that live.all() mistake.

Comment: Hmm after you changed that Entry line in urls.py, and after looking at your models.py, I don't see a syntax error anymore... are you sure you're still getting the same error?  If so, are you sure you re-deployed with the latest changes?

Comment: I think wich this error is not on this urls.py file and yep on main urls.py.

Comment: I think @RaelMax is right. This seems to indicate that the error bubbled up from the main `urls.py`.

Comment: Yes @Rael is right. It's from coltrane.models. <-- stupid dot! Thanks for helping!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In your main `urls.py` you have:

```
from coltrane.models. import Entry
```

Change that to:

```
from coltrane.models import Entry
```

That will fix this. :D

Answer (score 1):

Your model have a "live" manager?

Comment: Not sure what you mean but I pasted the models.py

Comment: In your entry_info_dict dict, change Entry.live.all() for Entry.objects.all().

Comment: Same error still showing up. Don't know where I got that live.all() mistake.

Comment: Hmm after you changed that Entry line in urls.py, and after looking at your models.py, I don't see a syntax error anymore... are you sure you're still getting the same error?  If so, are you sure you re-deployed with the latest changes?

Comment: I think wich this error is not on this urls.py file and yep on main urls.py.

Comment: I think @RaelMax is right. This seems to indicate that the error bubbled up from the main `urls.py`.

Comment: Yes @Rael is right. It's from coltrane.models. <-- stupid dot! Thanks for helping!